# Modified packet payload in Omnet++ INET

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to modify the payload of a packet in Omnet++ using hte INET framework. I would like to preserve the destination and other non-data infirmation. But I would like to modify the message/infor/data that the packet carries.

I have carefully read https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html but I don't see a method or way of actually modifying the data. There is the packetPrinter that tells me the size of the payload, I can even create a new packet with random bytes, but then I loose the destination information, which I don't want.

I would be grateful if someone would be able to provide me with help.
Thanks

Edit:

Here is the code:

```
auto packetCopy = packet->dup();
auto frontOffset = getIntDataLenght(packetCopy,"front");
auto packetCopy1 = packet->dup();
auto backOffset = getIntDataLenght(packetCopy1,"back");
auto packetCopy2 = packet->dup();
auto dataOffset = getIntDataLenght(packetCopy2,"data");
EV_INFO << "mitm" << endl;
EV_INFO << frontOffset << endl;
EV_INFO << backOffset << endl;
EV_INFO << dataOffset << endl;
std::vector<bool> bitVector (dataOffset);
if(dataOffset != 0){
    for(int i=0; i<=dataOffset; i++)
    {
        if(rand() % 2 ==0){
            bitVector.push_back(false);
        }else{
            bitVector.push_back(true);
        }
    }
    auto rawBitsData = makeShared<BitsChunk>();
    rawBitsData->setBits(bitVector);
    auto randomPacket = new Packet("DATA", rawBitsData);
    if (frontOffset != 0){
        EV_INFO << "Copying front part" << endl;
        auto frontPart = packetCopy->peekAtFront(packetCopy->getFrontOffset());
        randomPacket->insertAtFront(frontPart);
    }
    if (backOffset != 0){
        EV_INFO << "Copying back part" << endl;
        auto backPart = packetCopy->peekAtBack(packetCopy->getBackOffset());
        randomPacket->insertAtBack(backPart);
    }
    EV_INFO << "Sending modified packet" << endl;
    send(randomPacket, "transportOut");
}else{
    send(packetCopy, "transportOut");
}
```

Here is the getIntDataLenght function:

```
int Attacker_Ipv4::getIntDataLenght(Packet *packet, std::string part){
    inet::units::value<long long, inet::units::units::b> lenght;
    if (part.compare("front")){
        lenght = packet->getFrontOffset();
    }else if(part.compare("back")){
        auto backOffset = packet->getBackOffset();
        lenght = packet->getTotalLength()-backOffset;
    }else if(part.compare("data")){
        packet->trim();
        lenght = packet->getDataLength();
    }
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
    stream << lenght;
    std::string stringLenght = stream.str();
    stringLenght.pop_back();
    stringLenght.pop_back();
    int intDataLenght = std::stoi( stringLenght );
    return intDataLenght;
}
```

The code is obviously not in it's final state, but I thought that this would work.

Comment: Could you provide the sample code with the packet that carrying a payload as well as precise how you intend modify the packet?

Comment: Here is an example, I only want to modify the payloaf/data of the package, not the information like destiantion. I suppose these are not in the offsets, as this code fails due to the new packet being unknown